# OpenGL ES2.0 поворот камеры на градусы

Tags: android, opengles

Есть необходимость "крутить" камеру в OpenGL ES на определённое кол-во градусов в 3-х мерном пространстве. Другими словами менять точку, в которую смотрит камера в зависимости от градуса, на который она наклонена. Т.е, я хочу её сдвигать при скролинге пальцем по экрану. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: что вы попробовали уже сделать?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, я пробовал использовать код который когда-то использовал для трансформации точек, когда рисовал куб на канвасе. Но тут это не подошло

Comment: Похоже я нашел решение проблемы. Если eyeZ - lookZ = 1, то равенство: look[X или Y] = tan (angle). Если вам нужно оглянуться назад, тогда eyeZ - lookZ = -1. look[X Y Z] - точка, в которую смотрит камера, eye[X Y Z] - координаты камеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
float deltaZ = 4; // например 4, это может быть любое число
oglr.angleX += (downX-x)/10;
oglr.angleY += (y-downY)/10;
if (oglr.angleX > 90 && oglr.angleX < 270) oglr.lookZ = oglr.eyeZ + deltaZ;
else oglr.lookZ = oglr.eyeZ - deltaZ;
if (oglr.angleX < 0) oglr.angleX = 360+oglr.angleX;
if (oglr.angleX > 360) oglr.angleX = oglr.angleX%360;
oglr.lookX = oglr.eyeZ > oglr.lookZ ? (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(oglr.angleX))*(oglr.eyeZ-oglr.lookZ) + oglr.eyeX : (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(oglr.angleX-180))*(oglr.eyeZ-oglr.lookZ) + oglr.eyeX;
oglr.lookY = (float)Math.tan(Math.toRadians(oglr.angleY))*(Math.abs(oglr.eyeZ-oglr.lookZ)) + oglr.eyeY;
downX = x;
downY = y;
```

Примечание: oglr - OpenGLRenderer class; x, y - MotionEvent.getX(), getY()